# Purposes of different files in python installation

Tags: python

What are the purposes of `*.pyd` files in the `DLLs` directory, header files (`*.h`) in the `include` directory, and `*.lib` files in the `libs` directory? When I delete them it seems that at least some basic python code works properly.

Comment: Why are you randomly deleting parts of your Python installation? The most common version of Python is implemented in C, hence the header files. `.pyd` files are [like DLLs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll). `.lib` is either a [static library or an import library](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/windows.html#differences-between-unix-and-windows).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know. For the sake of the experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*.pyd are compiled python extensions (on windows). *.lib are library modules used for building and linking with python itself. The *.h are C include files needed when you are creating your own extensions.

Generally these are all quite small and do not consume material disk space. I recommend you leave them alone. even if you don't need them now, you may want them in the future (when it might be difficult to locate).